# How to verify windows narrator is running c#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, verify, narrator

In my case i have to decide whether the narrator is running or not.
I am using below line of code to check narrator is running .

`var isNarratorStarted = AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);.`

The above code returns true even when narrator is off and WindowsInspector is running.

My aim is to detect only Narrator is running or not.

Comment: For the testing, isNarratorStarted will not change immediately after Narrator app close. if we close the Narrator app a few seconds then check isNarratorStarted value, it will become false.

Comment: *The above code returns true even when narrator is off and WindowsApplicationDriver/WindowsInspector is running*.  I run `WindowsApplicationDriver` app but I could not reproduce this issue.

Comment: With WindowsInspector we can reproduce the issue.